# how can i use 'adb shell' command to know application response or current activity

Tags: android

I have created a batch file that fires adb shell command to start activity, send events to enter text into username and password text fields & click login buttons to navigate to other activity(screen).
                    how can i know that application navigate to other activity or want to know the response that tell me if login successful or not using shell commands.

Thanks,
Bhushan

Answer (score 1):

[Dollop](http://dollopmobile.com), where I work, provides a record-and-play-back tool for Android that will do the things you suggest and save you the hassle of interacting with low-level shell commands. (It is currently limited to running on Windows in communication with Android devices). It's easy to configure and use, requires no programming, runs against real devices (which do NOT have to be rooted) and automatically saves screenshots as it plays tests. I'd love to hear your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

try to get process (ps aux | grep xxxxx ) information to know the activity running or not

Comment: Thanks. But it is not of my concern. Actually i want to create a black box testing framework from where i have to run an android application and generate fail\pass reports. Do you have any idea or suggestion for me ?